# making web.config password protected and use it in application

Tags: asp.net

I want to make my web.config password protected so that external users do not open it. But my application should be able to access. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 3):

Rather than protecting file by password use Encrypt web config have look to this : [Encrypting Web.Config Values in ASP.NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

And some samples https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203213/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx